# passing array as parameter to a function

Tags: c++, arrays

this script is supposed to output array values that were inputted by the user into array "store." I am trying to store all the char array values into string temp. I get the error on line 12: "[Error] invalid conversion from 'char*' to 'char' [-fpermissive]." Would appreciate any help!

Edit: so I fixed the declaration and now at least it compiles, but the answer I get on my cmd is all jumbled up. Why is this so? The cmd only correctly couts the first string but after the space, it messes up.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>

using namespace std;
void coutArray(char[], int);
int main()
{
    char store[50];

    cout << "enter text: " << endl;
    cin >> store;
    coutArray(store, 50);

    system("pause");
    return 0;

}
void coutArray(char store[], int max)
{
    string temp = "";
    int i = 0;
    while (i < max)
    {
        temp += store[i];
        i++; 
    }
    cout << temp << endl;
}
```

Using input from all answerers I finally got the fixed code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <string>

using namespace std;
void coutArray(char[], int);
int main()
{
    char store[50] = {0};

    cout << "enter text: " << endl;
    cin.getline(store, 50);
    coutArray(store, 50);

    system("pause");
    return 0;

}
void coutArray(char store[], int max)
{
    string temp = "";
    int i = 0;
    while (i < max && store[i]!=0)
    {
        temp += store[i];
        i++; 
    }
    cout << temp << endl;
}
```

Thanks everyone.  i learned a lot!!!

Comment: your declaration takes a single `char`: `void coutArray(char, int);`. Fix that first.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> so I fixed the declaration and now at least it compiles, but the answer I get on my cmd is all jumbled up. Why is this so?

Not sure what you mean by jumbled up. But since you did not tell us what you typed its hard to know it looks like it worked to me:

```
> ./a.out
enter text:
Plop
Plop�ȏU�
```

Notice that since my input is only 4 characters long. This means that a lot of the characters in the array still have undefined (ie random values). This is why I am seeing junk. To get past this initialize the array to have all 0 values.

```
char store[50] = {0};
```

Even bettern use a C++ object than handles longer strings.

```
std::string store;
std::getline(std::cin, store);
```

Note: passing arrays to functions by value is not a good idea. On the other end they have decayed to pointers and thus do not act like arrays anymore (they act like pointers whose semantics are similar but not identical).

If you must pass an array pass it by reference. But I would use a C++ container and pass that by reference (it is much safer than using C constructs). Have a look at `std::string`

Comment: #include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <string>

using namespace std;
void coutArray(string[], int);
int main()
{
 string store[50] = {0};
 
 cout << "enter text: " << endl;
 getline(cin, store);
 coutArray(store, 50);
 
 system("pause");
 return 0;
 
}
void coutArray(string store[], int max)
{
 string temp = "";
 int i = 0;
 while (i < max)
 {
  temp += store[i];
  i++; 
 }
 cout << temp << endl;
}

Comment: ^ sorry i di the above modification but now i get another error:[Error] no matching function for call to 'getline(std::istream&, std::string [50])'

Comment: Its `std::string store;` not `std::string store[50] = {0};` The string is a C++ type and initializes and automatically sizes itself correctly. It also has a method called size() that will tell you how many characters are currently in side so you do not need to assume 50.

Answer (score 1):

When you get an input using "cin" your input automatically ends with 0 (NULL).
You just need to add one little piece of code to your while statement.

instead of this :

```
while (i < max)
```

use this :

```
while (i < max && store[i]!=0)
```

Now it will stop when the input string is finished and won't print any garbage existed in the array beforehand.

To show that cin does add terminating zero, i initialized the array to 46, and put a breakpoint after the cin

[image]

Comment: @LokiAstari - i wrote after initializing char store[50] the following code :  for(int i=0;i<50;i++)
  store[i]=46; 
And it still worked, so i'm not wrong !

Comment: But your idea of extending the while loop condition is perfectly good (ie a very good idea).

Comment: @LokiAstari as i told you my array doesn't have random values, all it's values initiated to 46 before calling "coutArray", and cin does add terminating 0 ! just run the code an see.. here is a print screen : http://i.imgur.com/PFmNa7b.png.  more over, if terminating zero wouldn't have been added you couldn't use cout.

Answer (score 0):

The declaration of the function is wrong. Should be void coutArray(char *, int);
Look at the [Implicit Conversion](http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/typecasting/) rules to understand what the compiler can do and what it cannot to do for you.

Comment: replace void coutArray(char, int); with void coutArray(char *, int);

Comment: Declaration is fine. There was a minor typo in the forward declaration that is now fixed.

Answer (score 0):

The issue with your program was that you were probably entering in less characters than the maximum size of the buffer. Then when you passed the maximum size as the parameter to `coutArray`, you assigned unfilled slots in the `char` array to `temp`. These unfilled slots could contain anything, as you have not filled them up to that point.

Your program is still correct, but what would be better would be to use `read` so that the number of bytes you specify is the minimum number of bytes that can be entered:

```
std::cin.read(store, 50);
```

Even better solution would be to use `std::string`:

```
std::string store;
std::cin >> store;

// or for the entire line
std::getline(std::cin, store);
```

It also follows that your `coutArray` should be changed to:

```
void coutArray(std::string);
// ...
void coutArray(std::string str)
{
    std::cout << str << std::endl;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Look at this way

```
template<typename T, size_t N>
void MyMethod(T (&myArray)[N])
{
    //N is number of elements, myArray is the array
    std::cout<<"array elements number = "<<N<<endl;

    //put your code
    string temp;
    temp.resize(N+1);//this is for performance not to copy it each time you use += operator
    int i = 0;
    while (i < max)
    {
        temp += store[i];
        i++; 
    }
    cout << temp << endl;
}
//call it like this
char arr[] = "hello world";
MyMethod(arr);
```